# How to optimize code without using regex?

Tags: java, regex, algorithm, optimization

My test assignment when hiring was to optimize this code:

```
someString.replaceAll("\"", "'").replaceAll("\n", "").replace("[]", "{}");
```

To solve this problem, I wrote this method:

```
public String outputValue(String input) {
   char[] inputArray = input.toCharArray();
   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
   for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
      if (i != inputArray.length - 1 && inputArray[i] == '[' && inputArray[i + 1] == ']' ) {
         builder.append("{}");
         i++;
      }
      else if (inputArray[i] == '"')
         builder.append("'");
      else if (inputArray[i] == '\n' )
         continue;
      else builder.append(inputArray[i]);
   }
   return  builder.toString();
}
```

I had many options for solving this problem, but this seemed the most optimal. I tested the speed using the **Instant** class, and on any line size it showed me high results. The firm told me that in their measurements there is degradation on large lines, that this is due to an overhead for using **StringBuilder** and unconditional allocation of a new line at the end.

So i didn't get a job.

What solution could be even more optimized? Even using a char array, I cannot do without string allocation **String.valueOf()**.

Comment: I consider your current chain of calls to `replaceAll` to already be optimal, at least from the point of view of code readability.

Comment: It probably would have helped to construct the `StringBuilder` with an initial length of `input.length()`: `StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(input.length());`

Comment: I would use `input.charAt(i)` instead of converting to a `char[]` (which copies the string). Also, you can use `input.regionMatches` to check substrings without copying.

Comment: @tim scaleability trumps readability if you need scaleability

Comment: @Bohemian Completely agree, but is that the case here?

Comment: One optimization can be to not convert the string into a char[] to avoid a copy, and access characters directly using charAt. Else, keep the convertion but do not use a StringBuilder and directly modify the char[], but it may be at the cost of moving chars a lot of times if there are many \n

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen well, as it was a hiring question, perhaps they were wanting OP to ask what was being optimized for?

Comment: Did you ask if all chars in the string were under decimal 128?

Comment: _The underlying implementation of String::replaceAll calls the java.util.regex.Pattern.compile() method each time it is called even if the first argument is not a regular expression. This has a significant performance cost and therefore should be used with care. String::replace does exactly the same thing as String::replaceAll without the performance drawback of the regex._ As you are just replacing single chars maybe the interviewer wanted you to change the call of `String::replaceAll` to `String::replace`

Comment: @Bohemian no, i didn't ask it. But the input values will come in the format html or xml.

Comment: @Eritrean i have now tested on input data size 1000000. With replaceAll I had the result 288ms, and with replace 275ms. But my solution shows 40ms.

Comment: Are you sure that not using regex is a requirement? You could have used a pre-compiled `Pattern`, then `pattern.matcher(input).replaceAll(/* some function */)`.

Comment: Considering all the discussion and answers generated I find it surprising that this question does not have more up votes.  So I'll be the first. +1

Comment: @Karada I asked because if all chars are ASCII, you can build a `byte[]` (not a `char[]`) and then convert that to a string, which would outperform using StringBuilder (even if initially sized up), due to recent changes to the internals of the String class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();`

StringBuilder has no idea how large the output is going to be, so you do get amortized growth cost here: SB isn't voodoo magic, it needs to guess at sizes. It'll guess 'eh, I'll give you 10 chars worth'. If you then add the 11th char, SB has to make a new char array (a larger one; I think it grows by a factor x2, might be x1.5), so it makes a 20-char array, copies over the first 10 chars, and tosses out the old array. This is not too bad (by definition this growth penalty is applied to an ever exponentially *decreasing* number of `append` operations), but...

look at the input question: The output string is as large as the input string, OR smaller (every `\n` in the input results in the output being 1 smaller). So, you can tell StringBuilder beforehand: Hey, just start out with this much capacity (the length of the input). Now there is no growth penalty anymore.

> that this is due to an overhead for using StringBuilder

This is misleading or oversimplified; you may not have quite heard that correctly. StringBuilder is just an object, with a char array. That is overhead, yeah, but,

> `someString.replaceAll("\"", "'").replaceAll("\n", "").replace("[]", "{}");`

that makes 2 pattern objects and (potentially) 3 strings. strings also are just an object with a big char array inside, so that's potentially **more overhead** and thus does not explain in the slightest why your take can be a lot slower.

However, there is another optimization you missed:

The `replace`/`replaceAll` methods don't make any string, *AT ALL*, if there is no need. Try it: `"Hello!".replace("Foo", "Bar")` returns the same reference (`a == b` equal).

Also, `.toCharArray` does require yet another full clone, also pricey. Just use `charAt`.

So, let's make an actual fast one:

```
public String outputValue(String input) {
   StringBuilder builder = null;
   int len = input.length();
   for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      char c = input.charAt(i);
      if (c != '[' && c != '\n' && c != '"') {
        if (builder != null) builder.append(c);
        continue;
      }

      if (builder == null) {
        // Don't even make the builder until we determine we need it!
        builder = new StringBuilder(len);
        builder.append(input, 0, i);
      }
      if (i != leg - 1 && c == '[' && input.charAt(i + 1) == ']' ) {
         builder.append("{}");
         i++;
      } else if (c == '"') {
         builder.append('\'');
      } else if (c != '\n') {
         builder.append(c);
      }
   }
   return  builder == null ? input : builder.toString();
}
```

> I tested the speed using the Instant class, and on any line size it showed me high results.

Not how you test performance. Instant represents system clock; it has only at best microsecond granularity (and usually not even that), and can and will change if the net time daemon changes the time on you. It can also be under smear (when a clock needs adjusting, because so much software out there assumes time can never run backwards, instead of just moving the time back, a smearing NTP will simply run time 'slower' - ticking up 750 milliseconds every second for example, until time's 'fixed').

Even nanoTime is not great, though - benchmarking is way more complicated than this. Use JMH (Java Microbenchmark Harness).

If you want to see some examples where your code does way worse than the original `.replaceAll/replaceAll/replace` chain, make a bunch of strings that are large and which do *not* contain any of these symbols (no newlines, no quotes, no brackets). You'll see a very big difference.

---

But, interview questions aren't neccessarily about code optimization. For example, I find these just as plausible:

1. Change almost nothing; replace is reasonably fast. However, `.replaceAll` involves a regex. If this line gets executed a ton, making an explicit pattern object would be more efficient *and* read better (though that is in the eye of the beholder). More generally, the patterns here don't use any regex features, so maybe the interviewer just wanted you to replace `replaceAll` with `replace` and that is all. To be clear, my code above *will* be faster if you have a large input with newlines *and* quotes *and* brackets in it, and will not be slower if there aren't. But, not every line of code needs to be optimized to the maximum possible extent.
2. Before digging into the code at all, the exercise tested your willingness to ask questions and look for the bigger picture first. Maybe they wanted you to ask: How often is this run? Is there a performance framework in place? What kinds of strings are usually thrown at this method? Can we perhaps look elsewhere and fix the strings 'at the source' instead of converting them every time? When I do an interview, I tend to craft technical questions that seem complete but which have some missing information once you dig down enough - if the interviewee doesn't ask, I dock them some points. It's not an instant fail - I'll tell em and see if they bother to ask and debate first before diving into programming for the next question.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know about JMH, now I will use it. This answer will help me not to be mistaken in the future.

Comment: All the `(builder != null)`-checks may be optimized by the VM, but I wouldn't count on it. I would do the check once in front of the loop. (Aceptiing the risk that the string only contains `\n` and the StringBuilder-creation wasn't necessary.)

Comment: @MrSmith42 that sounds either wrong or pointless. If you mean: Check once _before_ the loop, that would require looping twice, I don't think that route leads to more efficient code. If you mean: Write something like `boolean builderUnset = builder == null;` and then using that boolean - aboolean check is not faster than an `== null` check. But I may be wrong. However, I'm pretty sure. Something like a JMH profile report would absolutely convince me, though.

Comment: @rzwitserloot: Waht I meant is there are only two cases in which no creation of the StringBuilder is needed: 1. `input` has length 0 or 2. `input` only contains `\n` characters. If we ignore case 2 (most likely a very rare case) , you only need one check in front of the loop.

Comment: @MrSmith42 you seem to have misread the code. Your characterisation of when the builder is not made is completely off. Length is irrelevant, and e,g. the string "Hello, World" would __not__ lead to a stringbuilder being made. Did I program a bug someplace?

Comment: @rzwitserloot: You are right the case that no character needs to be changed slipped my mind.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the StringBuilder you could modify the `inputArray` directly and use it as result (possible, because your replaces can only shorten the char-sequence)

This would be my resulting version:

```
 public static String outputValue(final String input) {
        final char[] dataArray = input.toCharArray();
        int destPos = 0;
        int srcPos = 0;
        final int len = dataArray.length;
        while (srcPos < len) {
            if ('"' == dataArray[srcPos]) {
                dataArray[destPos++] = '\'';
                srcPos++;
                continue;
            }
            if ('\n' == dataArray[srcPos]) {
                srcPos++;
                continue;
            }
            if ('[' == dataArray[srcPos] && srcPos < len - 1 && ']' == dataArray[srcPos + 1]) {
                dataArray[destPos++] = '{';
                dataArray[destPos++] = '}';
                srcPos += 2;
                continue;
            }
            dataArray[destPos++] = dataArray[srcPos++];
        }
        return String.copyValueOf(dataArray, 0, destPos);
    }
```

Thoughts about the code:

- Memory consumption is the `dataArray` (and the created return-String).
- Speed: only profiling can tell if it's faster than using a StringBuilder with a predefined size.

Speed: I made rough speed test of the original, my own and the version of
rzwitserloot (with a long String `dats-len: 268435456 characters`
`output-len  251658240`

At least running from within eclipse, as JUnit-test,mine is faster than both the others.

Output of my test:

```
date-len 268435456     
out-len  251658240  
mr smith42:   1007
rzwitserloot: 1512
Orgiginal:    1950
mr smith42:   834
rzwitserloot: 1370
Orgiginal:    1870
mr smith42:   789
rzwitserloot: 1214
Orgiginal:    1945
mr smith42:   720
rzwitserloot: 1142
Orgiginal:    1572
mr smith42:   672
rzwitserloot: 1073
Orgiginal:    1739
mr smith42:   925
rzwitserloot: 1240   
Orgiginal:    1823  
mr smith42:   834  
rzwitserloot: 1284  
Orgiginal:    1676  
mr smith42:   840  
rzwitserloot: 1230  
Orgiginal:    1621 
mr smith42:   811  
rzwitserloot: 1260  
Orgiginal:    1695  
mr smith42:   840  
rzwitserloot: 1257  
Orgiginal:    1707  
mr smith42:   868  
rzwitserloot: 1309  
Orgiginal:    1716  
mr smith42:   837  
rzwitserloot: 1262  
Orgiginal:    1683  
mr smith42:   835  
rzwitserloot: 1240  
Orgiginal:    1632  
mr smith42:   824  
rzwitserloot: 1255  
Orgiginal:    1635  
mr smith42:   844  
rzwitserloot: 1243  
....
```

Here my rough test: (Using a real profiling tool should lead to similar results)

```
 @Test
    public void test() {

        String data = "jksdhfewfnku\n[] [  {} \"  [] }\nss";
        data += data;
        data += data;
        data += data;
        data += data;
        data += data;
        data += data;
        data += data;
        data += data;
        data += data;
        data += data;
        data += data;
        data += data;
        data += data;
        data += data;
        data += data;
        data += data;
        data += data;
        data += data;
        data += data;
        data += data;
        data += data;
        data += data;
        data += data;
        String expected = "jksdhfewfnku{} [  {} '  {} }ss";
        expected += expected;
        expected += expected;
        expected += expected;
        expected += expected;
        expected += expected;
        expected += expected;
        expected += expected;
        expected += expected;
        expected += expected;
        expected += expected;
        expected += expected;
        expected += expected;
        expected += expected;
        expected += expected;
        expected += expected;
        expected += expected;
        expected += expected;
        expected += expected;
        expected += expected;
        expected += expected;
        expected += expected;
        expected += expected;
        expected += expected;

        System.err.println("date-len " + data.length());
        System.err.println("out-len  " + expected.length());

        // run it multible times to give the VM a chance for optimization
        for (int i = 20; 0 < i; i--) {
            final long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Assert.assertEquals(expected, T.outputValue(data));
            System.err.println("mr smith42:   " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t));
            final long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Assert.assertEquals(expected, T.outputValue2(data));
            System.err.println("rzwitserloot: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t2));
            final long t3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Assert.assertEquals(expected, T.outputValueOrgiginal(data));
            System.err.println("Orgiginal:    " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t3));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

These interview questions are more about what questions you ask the interviewer. The interviewer is the customer and you are the contractor in to solve their problem.

It's their system, you were asked to optimize. What questions are you going to ask them?

The other case is that they have no idea how to optimize that line of code and they are just running some tools someone (much more talented than they are) made to find the bottle neck.

You are there to give them free code to run through their tools. You aren't getting the job because there wasn't one to begin with. Shady? Yes. Done often in all industries and all disciplines? Yes.